# Hide TortoiseSVN overlay icons everywhere

Tags: tortoisesvn, icons

I have recently discovered that TortoiseSVN allows hiding overlay icons through the

```
Right Click > TortoiseSVN > Settings > Icon Overlays
```

But apparently if i set the status cache to None i see that the icon overlays disappear for all the files but they still show up for folders.

So i tried disabling all Overlay handlers, restarted after the settings were applied and they are still there.

So i am wondering, is it possible to completely remove/disable all the traces of TortoiseSVN icon overlays?

I don't mind touching the registry, in fact i already have and found the TortoiseSVN keys in `HKLM/Software` and `HKCU/Software` but didn't find what i was looking for, or at least didn't recognize a possible key and if it can be done via a REG file that would even be better.

Here's a useful link: http://www.svntalk.com/node/3 to understand exactly what i did.

Answer (score 2):

Well in the end it wasn't so far from what i was doing.

In the same dialog, there's a `Exclude paths` section. I was adding a `*` thinking that it will be considered as a "Everything" wildcard but apparently it really only accepts absolute paths.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by changing "Status Cache" to "None" (as you suggest) and unchecking all "Drive Types". By default, "Fixed Drives" is checked, so icon overlays show up on C:\ and friends.